# flutter play local video simply without video_player plugin

Tags: flutter, dart

I am making application which plays local video simply.

At first I use https://pub.dev/packages/video_player,

```
video_player: ^0.10.2+1
```

However in some reason, it doesn't work in my environment, and more over only a few old version works on flutter `1.9` (my flutter is `1.9`)

So, now I want to use play video another plugin or without plugin.

But,I cant find any document, other than this plugin.

What I want to do is just playing one video with native video player.

Where should I start??

Comment: have you found any solution other than video_player plugin?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend updating your Flutter install with `flutter upgrade`. The current stable version is `1.12.13`, and most of the plugins owned by the Flutter team have bumped their minimum SDK version to `1.12.13`.

Comment: Thank you, but I need to use flutter 1.9,,, because some of third-party plugin does not support 1.12 yet...